# Max range of uint in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I am writing a smart contract in solidity and I have a question in relation to the range of **uint** type.

My understanding is that **uint** is the same as **uint256** and the range  of this is **0** to **2^256**.

I this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost got it: a `uint256` can contain numbers between `0` and `(2^256)-1`, inclusive. That's `2^256` different values.

`uint` is an alias for `uint256`. I myself like to be explicit, and favor `uint256` over `uint`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct.

Since that is too brief for SE, I'll, there is no point in `if(uintA < 0)` because it isn't possible. However `0-1` = `2^256-1` so use SafeMath.sol to avoid overflow/underflow conditions or similar nasties around basic math.

Hope it helps.